# Is "Written from her heart" idiomatic?

Tags: phrase-usage

In Hindi, or most Indian languages, a literal translation would mean "She is being very sincere in writing it" or "she is not putting any pretenses". Does it mean the same in English or is there a better way of conveying that meaning?

Comment: In English it means she is honestly expressing her feelings. "Written from *the* heart" would be more usual.

Comment: @Peter Your comment would make an excellent answer! This question is currently near the top of the "upvoted but unanswered questions" list here: https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3248/searches-for-finding-questions-that-need-attention

Answer (score 2):

"Written from her heart" is not common in English, though most people would understand it. The English idiom is "written from *the* heart", meaning she is honestly expressing her feelings. See [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/from%20the%20heart).